# Drop key from dictionary in dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, finance

Hi I created a dictionary from a pandas Dataframe of financial data. I am trying to pull two specific values from this data frame in a loop, after applying some calculations, and add it to a new data frame. To do this as an intermediary step I have created a new dictionary from the Dataframe (portfolios) which I will append to a list. In doing so it has listed the index number as an extra key inside every entry in the dictionary, ie it has created a dictionary inside a dictionary. I want to drop this second dictionary key which in this case is 992 and add that value to the outer dictionary key.

**note** portfolios is a larger Dataframe from which I pulled this specific entry

below is the head of the larger portfolios dataframe:

```
portfolios.head()
    Returns  Volatility  MMM Weight  ABT Weight  ...  ADBE Weight  AMD Weight  AAP Weight  AES Weight
0  0.376267    0.221238    0.181285    0.048288  ...     0.113503    0.164995    0.004576    0.040676
1  0.323802    0.193708    0.197259    0.001254  ...     0.162608    0.151378    0.059675    0.096442
2  0.398189    0.224429    0.067056    0.169859  ...     0.142113    0.184807    0.031413    0.027089
3  0.225460    0.172322    0.063022    0.100758  ...     0.075529    0.015270    0.134864    0.136784
4  0.325828    0.212882    0.148907    0.193622  ...     0.022118    0.096442    0.082162    0.004809
```

This is my code to grab and convert the specific entry I want:

```
list2 = []

GVCindex = portfolios[portfolios['Volatility']==portfolios['Volatility'].min()].index.tolist()

dictGVC = portfolios.loc[GVCindex].to_dict()

list2.append(dictGVC)

fin = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(list2)
```

Here is what it currently looks like:

```
>>> list2
[{'Returns': {932: 0.14045532455897075}, 'Volatility': {932: 0.1582942016003597}, 'MMM Weight': {932: 0.18494322390344745}, 'ABT Weight': {932: 0.029906861753963284}, 'ABBV Weight': {932: 0.1837038795739978}, 'ABMD Weight': {932: 0.0062650919515888715}, 'ACN Weight': {932: 0.15793314037253936}, 'ATVI Weight': {932: 0.0644399756626248}, 'ADBE Weight': {932: 0.01200620828052462}, 'AMD Weight': {932: 0.024667578415588958}, 'AAP Weight': {932: 0.149085877589782}, 'AES Weight': {932: 0.18704816249594283}}]
```

This is what I would like it to look like:

```
>>> list2
[{'Returns': 0.14045532455897075, 'Volatility': 0.1582942016003597, 'MMM Weight': 0.18494322390344745, 'ABT Weight': 0.029906861753963284}]
```

here is the finished Dataframe:

**This Dataframe was created from a larger list 2 than in the example above***

```
>>> fin.head()
                      Returns                  Volatility                   MMM Weight  ...                   AFL Weight                   A Weight                   APD Weight
0   {823: 0.4641212481398529}  {823: 0.24708090579365835}   {823: 0.03427725029749016}  ...                          NaN                        NaN                          NaN
1  {788: 0.47643150225144204}   {788: 0.2508983879170438}   {788: 0.03386593631658274}  ...  {788: 0.046989535272586806}                        NaN                          NaN
2   {32: 0.45814683192368877}   {32: 0.25089789807674673}    {32: 0.07310079951400653}  ...                          NaN  {32: 0.01274115108933681}                          NaN
3  {216: 0.47680922654636615}   {216: 0.2544050792473164}   {216: 0.06114500772292474}  ...                          NaN                        NaN  {216: 0.058250849997334514}
4  {853: 0.45735781176585616}  {853: 0.23667403702327827}  {853: 0.027942223122145397}  ...   {853: 0.06445688077317947}                        NaN                          NaN

[5 rows x 15 columns]
```

Comment: Long story short I have a dictionary in a dictionary and need to drop the second dictionary key. I tried .pop and del but not sure how to apply it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason my values were returning in this way is because DataFrame.to_dict has a default layout as follows:

‘dict’ (default) : dict like {column -> {index -> value}}

to solve this I changed the orient to records, that is I set:

dictoptimal = portfolios.loc[optimal1I].to_dict(orient='records')